# Polynomial that is surjective $\mod n$ for all $n$?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I was curious about an existence of the following polynomial
$f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $f(x) \not = x$ such that
given any $n \in \mathbb{N}$,
$f: \mathbb{Z} / n\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} / n\mathbb{Z} $
is a surjective. In other words, $f$ permutes the residue class modulo 
$n$ for every $n$. I was wondering if $f(x) = x$ would be only such polynomial or not?
Would someone be able to tell me what the situation is?
Thanks!

Comment: Note that $-x$ permutes things too.

Comment: and $x\mapsto\pm x+m$, $m\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: ooops. I forgot about the other linear ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be noted that the induced map $f_n\colon\mathbb Z/(n)\to\mathbb Z/(n)$ should be injective, then for all $m\in\mathbb Z$, we have $f(m+1)-f(m)=\pm1$, for otherwise, if it's non-zero, consider $n=\lvert f(m+1)-f(m)\rvert$. Now it follows from the asymptotic information that the polynomial $f$ should be of the form $c\pm x$.

**EDIT:** The last step of the preceding argument is analytic. Let's consider an algebraic method: Since $f$ is a polynomial, the difference $g(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$ is also a polynomial. Note that $g(m)=\pm1$, by pigeon-hole principle, there are infinitely many $m$'s, such that $g(m)=1$, or infinitely many $m$'s, such that $g(m)=-1$. Note that $g$ is a polynomial, we must have $g\equiv1$ or $g\equiv-1$. Q.E.D.